References on Newton-Cartan Gravity
I'm interested in learning a bit about Newton-Cartan gravity, and I would like some references on the topic. I am already familiar with differential geometry and general relativity, so those could be taken as prerequisites for the references. My main focus is to understand Newtonian gravity geometrically, so I'm hoping for a good discussion of that, but it is certainly a bonus if the reference discusses further developments.

Have you checked the PhD thesis of Roel Andringa?

@DanielC No, I haven't


First, the MTW book has a chapter 12 on Newton-Cartan (NC) theory, but it is rather outdated in the sense that some important results were obtained after this book was published.

A book by D. Malament Topics in the Foundations of General Relativity
and Newtonian Gravitation Theory
OA pdf, has a rather detailed account of NC theory. The book is aimed at students without prior knowledge of GR so a more advanced reader can skip the first chapters.

Lecture notes Newton–Cartan gravity by Philip Schwartz  require prior knowledge of differential geometry and general relativity. The second half of the  notes uses more advanced machinery of principal fibre bundles.

Review on non-relativistic gravity by Hartong, Obers & Oling provides an overview of the theory too brief to serve as an introduction, but it provides a lot of references on recent advances so it is a good starting point for an indepth research.



ooh the lecture notes by Philip Schwartz are nice and systematic, and certainly much more readable (from a modern ‘language’ sense) than Cartan :) +1

I don’t have very many in-depth references, but, here’s a brief list:

Elie Cartan - On Manifolds with Affine Connections and the Theory of General Relativity (original French in 1923, translated to English in 1986). Given that it is written by Cartan himself it might be a little more difficult to read, and also because at the time he was developing his own notation for the calculus of vector-valued forms. But once you get over those initial hurdles, I think it’s a nice introduction (and motivation) for some of the topics pertaining to relativity and gravity. Chapters 1 and 5 are probably most relevant. From my recollection, Cartan doesn’t introduce two degenerate metrics, but instead directly formulates things at the level of connections.

Andrzej Trautman - Foundations and Current Problems of General Relativity. Chapter 5 is most relevant, and particularly sections 5.3-5.5 are about the Newtonian theory.

Godinho, Natario - An Introduction to Riemannian Geometry, With Applications to Mechanics and Relativity. Well first of all, this is a nice book all around especially with applying differential geometry to classical mechanics and GR; it has nice problems which helps with putting the theory into practice. Section 6.3 is titled The Cartan Connection; this is just a one page summary followed by a single question to get you to work out some intermediate calculations… i.e this is a very brief ‘introduction’ to the topic, essentially in exercise format.


But really, my favourite read has been Cartan; this is one of the situations where I actually enjoyed reading from the source.
